# How to burn a cd that automatically opens a PDF upon insertion?

Tags: pdf, burning, compact-disc, nero

A friend of mine is using Nero Express. She would like to burn a cd with a pdf on it, and have the cd automatically open the pdf file when the cd is inserted into a machine running Windows.

Is there a way to achieve this using Nero Express or in general? Would this have to be achieved using `autorun.inf`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to create an [autorun.inf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf) file and place it in the root directory on the CD.  For example:

```
[autorun]
open=MyPDF.pdf
label=My Product Catalogue
```

Comment: This'll look awkward on the few computers without a PDF viewer. Any way to alternatively specify e.g. a portable PDF viewer on the CD if no default is present?

Comment: If you can find one (I don't know of any but there probably is one) then just use `open=\path\to\pdf\viewer.exe \path\to\PDFfile.pdf` in the autorun.inf  Doon't specify drive letters and it should be relative to the root of the CD drive the disk is inserted into.